# Select rows when 2 cells appear the same in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a way to select the rows from Dataframe 1 where the values of column 'A' and 'B' appear the same as in Dataframe 'a' and 'b'. The corresponding column names are different, so 'A' is not the same as 'a'.

Example:

Dataframe 1:

```
    A   B   C
0  10  20  30
1  40  50  60
2  70  80  90
```

Dataframe 2:

```
    a   b
0  10  20
1  40   0
2  70  80
```

The selected rows would be:

```
    A   B   C
0  10  20  30
2  70  80  90
```

Comment: are you looking for `A` to `a` and `B` to `b` matching or element wise match based on the second dataframe, what if the second dataframe had columns `c` and `d` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) and index on the columns of `df1`:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on=['A', 'B'], right_on=['a','b'])[df1.columns]

   A   B   C
0  10  20  30
1  70  80  90
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I somehow get the rows that are excluded?

Comment: Yes, just exclude the indexing step `df1.merge(df2, left_on=['A', 'B'], right_on=['a','b'])` @KristófKövér Oh and don't forget you can upvote and accept

Comment: I mean getting the excluded rows, not the columns come with df2. What I mean is practically splitting df1 into two dataframes by the condition this merge defines.

Comment: Yes, can't cose now but check the indicator argument @kristof